# How can I adjust Textmate syntax highlighting in Smarty literal tags

Tags: smarty, syntax-highlighting, textmate

So I have the Smarty TM bundle installed and active in Textmate, but I have a problem with the way it treats stuff inside of Smarty's `literal` tags.

As seen in this example: http://pastie.textmate.org/private/v3amipi5ukpg7vlcivixw

If I put Smarty `literal` tags inside of my HTML `script` tags, TM sees the stuff within the script tags as JS and highlights it appropriately. If I move those `literal` tags such that they are around my script, Textmate loses track of the fact that the `script` tags contain javascript--or even that the `script` tags *are* HTML--neither are highlighted.

I hate putting my literal tags inside the script because everything that deals with JS in the editor (for example, I have a TM command to run my JS through JSHint) gets mad at them being there unless I prefix them with JS comments (like in my pasted example). But prefixing them with comments is extra work I don't feel like doing, and causes lots of empty comments in my outputted source.

I have looked at the various lang definitions involved, and just cannot figure out what the heck to do to fix it. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Jim